# Launching JAR file from network drive using remote origin

Tags: java, javafx-8, executable-jar

I have an application implemented in JavaFX and it will be migrated to the web platform, but it will take some time for that.

Meanwhile, I am struggling with some problems regarding its uses. Some users need to launch the jar from a network drive because their machines do not have access to the the database. Only the drive where the jar is located has access to the database.

My doubt is whether running the jar from the allowed network drive will solve this problem. In addition, can JNLP be a solution for this ?

I'd appreciate any help about this.

Answer (score 1):

> Some users need to launch the jar from a network drive because their machines do not have access to the the database. Only the drive where the jar is located has access to the database.  My doubt is whether running the jar from the allowed network drive will solve this problem.

It won't work directly.

JavaFX is a client technology, it runs on a client PC.  If the client PC does not have direct access to a database, then neither does a JavaFX application running on that client PC.

> In addition, can JNLP be a solution for this ?

No, not for direct access to the database from the client if this isn't permitted in your network architecture, you would need a middle tier in addition to the JNLP based client to accomplish this.

---

*Discussion of some solutions to this problem*

Typically, the architecture of what you are describing would be built as a [multi-tier app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture).

1. A client tier, which is the the JavaFX application or HTML javascript application running on a client machine.
2. An application server tier which handles server logic.
3. A database tier which hosts the DBMS.

There is a reasonable [high level overview of such an architecture here](https://way2java.com/java-general/introduction-to-2-tier-and-3-tier-architecture/).

Often, nowadays, the application server will serve REST APIs of JSON data, which a HTML based JavaScript web application can easily consume.  Such APIs are also easily consumed using JavaFX applications which embed a REST client.  An application server services the REST APIs and communicates with a database over JPA or JDBC as appropriate.  However, than are many alternate technologies for client/server communication, and you can choose whatever you feel is a good fit for your application, development style and organization.

*Spring product specific discussion*

As you state your preference to use Spring, consider a [JavaFX SpringBoot application](https://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#adding-resource-bundles-to-the-view).

Spring also includes a technology called [spring remoting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) for facilitating client/server access.  Spring remoting provides for multiple communication technologies.  I'd advise sticking to the straight HTTP REST based technologies rather than other techniques such as RMI or AMQP as a HTTP REST based back-end can also serve as the backend for a standard HTML/JavaScript webapp which you also mention may be an eventual target client for your application.

If using Spring on client and server, checkout Spring's [AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html), and invoke JavaFX's [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) API inside the success and failure callbacks of the rest template.  Or, use a Spring [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) and control calls to the server via [JavaFX concurrency mechanisms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).  Not sure which would be best for you, possibly the standard RestTemplate wrapped in a [JavaFX Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Doing this in the correct manner will allow your application UI to remain responsive while it performs network activity (not block the UI thread) and also ensure that you don't violate JavaFX thread rules (don't access controls or modify data bound to JavaFX scene controls off of the JavaFX application thread).

Comment: Hi @jewelsea, thanks for your prompt response. I had the same idea about this, but I had to confirm it. This is a requirement that is typical for a client-server or web platform. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @jewelsea, after your answer, I've started to design the client side using the current JavaFX application integrated with Spring. Hence, I can easily communicate with the server side using REST calls. I'm very comfortable with Spring. The server side also will be implemented using Spring, serving REST API's of JSON data and communicating with the Database through JPA. What do you think ?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty standard approach to me, should work fine.  There are [some resources on Spring/JavaFX application integration](https://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), in case that assists you.  Note, you don't necessarily need to use Spring on the client as in the linked documentation, you could just use it on the server and access the server from your JavaFX application via any kind of Java REST client.  How you build it is up you and depends upon the amount of Spring integration you prefer to place within the client code.

Comment: I wil check it out and see if a really need Spring on the client side. Cheers!

Comment: Note Spring also includes a technology called [spring remoting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) for facilitating client/server access.  If using Spring on client and server, checkout Spring's [AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html), and invoke JavaFX's [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) API inside the success and failure callbacks of the rest template.